# String reference not set to an instance of a string. Parameter name: s C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to update the data using the picturebox button in the data gridview. Here is my code. Here is where the error is.

```
private void dgv_Member_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{   
    string colName = dgv_Member.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    if (colName == "colEdit")
    {
        AddNewMember add = new AddNewMember(this);
        add.btnSave.Enabled = false;
        add.btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        add.txtAcctno.Enabled = false;
        add.txtAcctno.Text = _AccountNo;
        add.dtpBDate.Value = DateTime.Parse(_Birthdate);
        add.dtpMembership.Value = DateTime.Parse(_DateofMembership);
        add.ShowDialog();
```

But I got this error:

> String reference not set to an instance of a string. Parameter name: s

The error pointed at:

```
add.dtpBDate.Value = DateTime.Parse(_Birthdate);
add.dtpMembership.Value = DateTime.Parse(_DateofMembership);
```

Comment: Are you *sure* those variables are not null?

Comment: where is `_DateofMembership` declared and assigned?

Comment: Looks like attempting to call `Parse()` on a null argument.